# Matrix question meaning of this question?

Tags: matrices

I understand about inverting and transposing a matrix.

But I am not sure what this question is asking me to do?

[image]

I can figure it out but I could not find a link online to explain.

Am I supposed to:

1. Get the inverse of A
2. Show that is is equal to the A transpose
3. Which should equal to A

Comment: Please enter critical parts of your questions as text, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions, instead of pasting pictures of them. Without that image your question is incomprehensible, making it inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries. See [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) to “How to ask a good question.”

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to show that 
$$
A^T = A
$$
by computing the first and comparing it to the second. THen you're also supposed to show that
$$
A^{-1} = A
$$
which you could do by computing the first and showing it equals the second, but which you could also do by showing that 
$$
A \cdot A = I
$$
so that $A$ is *an* inverse of $A$, hence (by a small theorem) must be *the* inverse of $A$.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure about suing the inverse technique for the second part. For example the determinant I get is 342 which is not right. It means x1 = 2/49. But for A * A Just squaring A? (small theorem)

Comment: A \cdot A = I for just the first x1 = 4/49 which is not correct as (14/343) 2/49 so for

Comment: So you must mean multiply the determinate A(1/7)*A(1/7) = 1/49 nice thanks!

Comment: I can't make sense of any of these comments, but I hope that my answer helped you understand the question.

Comment: Sorry I am kind of in panic mode my exams are coming up, I appreciate your time and it did help me a bit I am still not 100% sure but I am on the right track